# Unknown File Encoding

Tags: file-encodings

I've got a configuration file with some encoding which I'm not sure about. How would I go about decoding it so that it's readable?

Here's a sample:

```
xÚ³II,I´ãå´ÉËOIUÈL±U*®,öÌKËW
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If it is just text encoding problem you should be able to open it in some advance editor, or even a browser.
However, I think this is a configuration files that its data is written in binary format. Unless you know the application and the context, you won't be able to read it.

Comment: If it's binary format, you would need to look at the source code of the application to see what's being stored and how it's being stored. If the source code isn't available, you're out of luck.